# Python subprocess on Windows: stderr output in stdout (but not if I run the command in cmd.exe)

Tags: windows, python-2.7, cmd, subprocess

I want my python script to process the result of the `sigcheck.exe` tool.
The following command, when run in `cmd.exe` prints out a banner (this seems to be the stderr output) and writes the stdout output to a csv file:

```
sigcheck64 -c c:\tmp\unsigned.exe > csv_output.csv
```

This displays the stdout output and writes stderr (the header) into a file:
    sigcheck64 -c c:\tmp\unsigned.exe 2> csv_output.csv

However, if I try to do this in python, both the stdout and the stderr outputs are in stdout.

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(["sigcheck64.exe","-c", c:\tmp\unsigned.exe"], 
                      shell=True,
                      stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                      stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

o,e = p.communicate()
print("stdout: %s" % o)
print("stderr: %s" % e)
```

I could not find a way to separately get the stdout output. I tried other subprocess function and I tried to redirect stderr to devnull.

I could parse the merged output, but this would be ugly and, moreover, I want to understand what is going on here.

Comment: It looks like a bug in sigcheck.exe that causes it to ignore stderr if stdout is a pipe instead of a console or disk file. You could set `stdout` to a temporary file instead of a pipe. But I don't know why you'd care to keep the banner instead of using the `-nobanner` option. Also, `shell=True` shouldn't be used here. And if you do need `shell=True` in the future, it's wrong to use a list with the shell (i.e. on Windows, `subprocess.list2cmdline` does not create a command line that's intended for the shell); use a command-line string.

Comment: If you want to see this reproduced in CMD, try `sigcheck64 -c c:\tmp\unsigned.exe 2>stderr.txt | more`.

Comment: This explains why and solves my problem. Thanks.